# Express router not handling '/' when redirecting

Tags: node.js, express, router, express-router

I have a very simple express app. I'm using router to redirect and i have the following:

`router.js` (this works fine)

```
router.use('/dashboard', dashboard)
```

`dashboard.js` (this works fine)

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    req.user.role === 'admin' ? res.redirect('dashboard/admin') : res.redirect('/dashboard/mod')
})

router.get('/admin', admin)
```

`admin.js` (here is the problem)

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('working')})
```

when I reach this point, I get: **Cannot GET /dashboard/admin/** but I tried:

`admin.js`

```
router.get('/admin', async(req, res) => {
res.send('working')})
```

and it works, why isn't '/' not working in `admin.js` but when i repeat '/admin' it does? It works when I redirect from router to dashbord, but not when I redirect from dashboard to admin.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps change `router.get('/admin', admin)` to `router.use('/admin', admin)`.

Comment: Also, use absolute paths so change `res.redirect('dashboard/admin')` to `res.redirect('/dashboard/admin')` and so on.  I think relative paths may have been biting you.